# Cannot daisychain ToSort() to the list creation

Tags: c#

I'm creating a list of 20 random numbers and then sorting it with the following code:

```
var testList = Enumerable.Range(0, 10 + rand.Next(10))
                          .Select(r => rand.Next(100))
                          .ToList();
testList.Sort();
```

This works without any problem. However, I thought I could combine it all into one line with:

```
var testList3 = Enumerable.Range(0, 19)
              .Select(r => rand.Next(100))
              .ToList().Sort();
```

However, this generates an error

> Cannot assign void to an implicitly typed variable.

I don't think the `var` is the real problem though, because I still get an error if I explicitly type it as `List<int>`. In this case, the message changes to

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to Systems.Collections.Generic.List'

I don't mind the two lines instead of one but if anyone could explain why this happening, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `Sort()` doesn't return a collection

Comment: There's also [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) (to be called before ToList)